# tooltipster - make div as 'content' with css changes in div reflected in content

Tags: html, tooltipster

I want to assign a div to the tooltip content.  One way is to have a inline div as given in the example in website:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-tooltip').tooltipster({
        content: $('<span><img src="my-image.png" /> <strong>This text is in bold case !</strong></span>')
    });
});
```

However what I want is to have div seperately define like:

```
<span id='abc'><span><img src="my-image.png" /> <strong>This text is in bold case !</strong></span></span>
```

and then define content as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-tooltip').tooltipster({
        content: $($('#abc').html())
    });
});
```

The reason I want to do this is because I am making dynamic css changes to `'#abc'` and everytime the tooltipster shows I want recent css changed to be incorporated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#my-tooltip').tooltipster({
    functionBefore: function(origin,continueTooltip){
    origin.tooltipster('content',origin.children().html());
    continueTooltip();
    }
 });
```

For me worked that improved version :)

```
 $('#my-tooltip').tooltipster({
    functionBefore: function(origin,continueTooltip){
    origin.tooltipster('content',origin.next().contents());
    continueTooltip();
    }
 });
```

That is even better! :) But make sure your tooltip content is just after your selector here .tip follows after div#my-tooltip and also is its child.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to having the content be separately defined, I wanted the content for the tooltip to be nested inside the element that is clicked/hovered. I found the `functionBefore` option worked for me.

The markup might be:

```
<div id="my-tooltip">
    click/hover me to show a tooltip
    <div class="tip" style="display:none">
        tooltip<br>content
    </div>
</div>
```

And the js:

```
$('#my-tooltip').tooltipster({
    functionBefore: function(origin,continueTooltip){
        origin.tooltipster('content',origin.find('.tip'));
        continueTooltip();
    }
});
```